# Indefinite Flutter TextFormFields

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm building a registration UI and one of the fields needed is a "list" of emails. I don't know how long this list will be for each user. I was thinking of showing 1 textinputfield inside the form, and as the user ends writing in that one, another one shows up and so on... I don't think I can do this with Visibility or similar widgets, since to use them I would have to know how many emails I wanted, so I'm wondering if there's any other way I can achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a variable (outside of the `build` method) tracking how many text fields are needed, and then render them in a `Column` or a `ListView`.

For example, something like:

```
Column(
  children: _myListOfTextFields,
)
```